# Асинхронная обработка данных в Python

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp

Я написал парсер, сделал его асинхронным, парсит очень много данных, около 11к ссылок за 20 секунд, но обработка данных и отправка сообщений занимает от 4 до 15 минут. Как можно сделать обработку в реальном времени?

```
async def get_data(session, symb: str):
    try:
        await bot.wait_until_ready()
        channel = bot.get_channel(891762344303140935)
        url = f'https://example.com/{symb}'
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            resp_text = await resp.text()
            resp_dict = await resp.json()
            for result in resp_dict['results']:
                ticker = str(result['tickers']).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("',", ",").replace("'", "$")
                dat = str(result['published_utc']).replace("T", " ").replace("Z", "")
                ur = result['article_url']
                if not os.path.exists('./data'):
                    pickle.dump(dat, open('data', 'wb'))
                    await channel.send(f'{dat}\n{ticker}\n{ur}')
                    print(f"{ticker}\n{dat}\n{ur}\n--------------------------------------")
                else:
                    date = pickle.load(open('data', 'rb'))
                    if dat > date:
                        pickle.dump(dat, open('data', 'wb'))
                        await channel.send(f'{dat}\n{ticker}\n{ur}')
                        print(f"{ticker}\n{dat}\n{ur}\n--------------------------------------")
            return resp_text
    except ClientConnectorError:
        pass
    except KeyError:
        pass

async def site_data():
    while True:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            tasks = []
            text_file = open("nas_spis.txt", "r")
            lines = text_file.readlines()
            for g in lines:
                cat = str(g).replace("\n", "")
                task = asyncio.create_task(get_data(session, cat))
                tasks.append(task)
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)



bot.loop.create_task(site_data())
```

Answer (score 0):

Вижу проблему тут

```
pickle.dump\load(dat, open('data', 'wb'))
```

которая убивает всю асинхронность вставая в очередь для записи в файл. Так же объём записи данных будет не менее 10мб (11к ссылок по 1байту как минимум), что грузит оперативку, что замедляет питон.
Могу предложить использовать базы данных.

Comment: Базу данный типа sql предлагаете?

Comment: да, оптимальное решение, на мой взгляд sqlite в памяти,- не требуется доступ к диску (конечно следует учитывать размер оперативки). Если не нравятся sql то то можно использовать redis, или модуль mmap. Суть в том чтобы постоянно не писать\читать с диска, это занимает кучу времени, либо сбрасывать на диск обработаные данные и "забывать" об этом файле, обрабатывать какнить потом.

Comment: sqlite в оперативной памяти? для меня это пока что-то новое, буду изучать , спасибо за ответ!

Comment: con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

Comment: 11k ссылок по 1 байту получится 11 килобайт. А даже если и 10 мб  - всего лишь 10мб никоим образом не "грузят оперативку" и не "замедляют питон".

Comment: Нет смысла тут в БД. В функции в один и тот же файл сохраняется одно значение (максимальная дата?), так что нужно это значение просто в переменной хранить в памяти не заморачиваясь с БД. Это сэкономит чуть-чуть времени (но я бы сильно не надеялся - этот файл во время работы программы наверняка в дисковом кеше лежит, и обращение к нему и так быстрое после первого раза). Нужно измерять где тратится время (я подозреваю, что `channel.send` съедает большую его часть)

Comment: Ребята, помогите. Пробовал sql в оперативную, тоже так, никаких изменений, что можете еще посоветовать. заметил такую вещь, когда начинает отправлять сообщения, он сразу несколько отправляет кучкой с разными временами, и естественно все актуальные. Может обработку в отдельную функцию взять и подключить multiprocessing? но как это сделать пока не знаю. @RomanKonoval - да, в файл сохраняется максимальная дата

Comment: Трудно посоветовать. Непонятно, что именно вы называете обработкой (все что в цикле?) Непонятно, текущее состояние кода (избавились ли от файла в частности?) и т.д. Чтоб подход был системным, а не хаотическим, нужно делать так: 1. находите какая часть кода какую часть времени выполнения занимает (это называется profiling). буквально нужно понимать какая строка какой вклад вносит, чтобы знать какую нужно оптимизировать 2. оптимизируете часть, которая занимает много времени. т.е. пробуете варианты, если не очевидно, что вариант принесет пользу, и измеряете опять.

Comment: Как профилировать/измерять - это отдельный (широкий) вопрос. Как найдете, что занимает время - можно опять задать вопрос по тому, как это оптимизировать. Советовать изменения не зная, что именно медленно - это совет пальцем в небо. Я уже писал выше, что подозреваю, что основное время занимает посылка сообщений по сети (`channel.send`), но это нужно подтвердить измерениями. Если это так - то можно попытаться посылать не одну строку в сообщении а сразу несколько.

Comment: @RomanKonoval я убрал channel.send, оставил только date = pickle.load(open('data', 'rb')), задержка не изменилась, всё так же 10 минут. Скорей всего это и замедляет. Но как это ускорить не знаю. Записать его в переменную в оперативную память не вариант, так как иногда скрипт придется перезапускать, и каждый раз буду получать много сообщений пока последняя дата не появится, а ссылок 11к

Comment: Начните с того, что уберите чтение этого файла на каждой итерации. Прочитайте один раз перед циклом значение и дальше используйте переменную, сохраняя ее в файл только когда новое (большее) значение увидели. Сейчас ведь читается файл, каждый раз без нужды.

Comment: Вообще-то записать переменную в оперативную память это вариант, точнее варианты: a) функция atexit сохраняет последнее значение в файл, при запуске берётся значение из файла. (не решит проблемы с крахом всей системы) б) использвать mmap где будет вспомагательная программа висеть в фоне и блокировать удаление участка памяти. Но эти потуги дадут мало-мало полагаю сотые секунды. Как вариант могу предложить не асинхронность, а многопоточность.

Comment: @ganz пробовал много вариантов, ничего успехов не дало. Остался только один вариант это как вы писали многопоточность, но вот не знаю как его сделать

Comment: Если убрали чтение из файла на каждой итерации и это не помогло, значит у вас узкое место не в `pickle.load(open(..))`. Пока не найдете узкое место, все исправления - это все на авось. Что делать я уже писал выше.

Comment: 11к ссылок только парсятся либо же выполняется 11к запросов? если второе, то на мой взгляд часа три будет хорошим результатом. & недавно прочёл о модуле uvloop, который якобы быстрее асинк в 10 раз, но сам не проверял

Comment: 11к ссылок парсятся и выводят все данные в консоли за 20 секунд, а вот дальше перебирать актуальное уже тяжко приходится ему

Comment: То есть программа потом будет загружать с этих страниц?

Comment: объясню суть программы. Я купил api на новости акций в реальном времени, акций 11к, api работает с get запросом и дает результат в json, ссылку на новость, дату публикации и названия акции, самые новые новости он отправляет в дискорд сервер. Я измерил скорость парса этих акций, заняло 20 секунд, а вот каждый json разобрать и сравнить с последней датой занимает 3-8 минут, это не считая отправку сообщения в дискорд, да и не думаю что отправка сообщения какое то время займет